# How to display Facebook public page feed in PHP website, without reaching Graph API quota limit?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a **custom Facebook Feed plugin** for a **custom CMS**, to display the 10 latest posts of our client's public Facebook page in a fancy way, with attachments. But we have issues with very limited quota and often it goes beyond 100% and the plugin crashes.

So at my company we created a facebook app with all the necessary authorisations to use the Graph API requests and it works well. But each page load on the frontend (where there is Facebook feed present) was using like 10% of the quota. So I implemented some cache and storing the attachments locally, and I was able to get down to 2% of the quota for each page load.

But it still means that 50 visits at the same time = 100% = over limit !

So I'm kind of stuck with it, and don't know what are the best practices in this field.

The facebook official doc says that **the quota on the Graph API depends on the number of app users**, but we don't want (or need) to have user connection since we just want to use Graph API to display posts from public pages on our clients' websites.

Comment: Locally with the user? If so, you should cache the content on the CMS server, then you can control exactly how many requests are made to Facebook.

Comment: _“But it still means that 50 visits at the same time = 100% = over limit !”_ - not sure what you mean by that. But it sounds like you did not implement caching properly?

Comment: @ misorude: I meant that if each set of requests to display the feed uses 2% of my quota, then 50 visits on the website at (almost) the same time means that I reach 100%.

But yes the solution is probably to do more caching. I will try getting only the most recent post, check if it's cached already. If not cached it means that it is a new post, so I will cache it on the CMS server, and then get the second one and repeat. This could mean less big queries, only if there is news on the page feed. I will post updates here to confirm if it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

It appears that you can put a **?limit=[X]** to the **/[page-id]/feed** API call, even though the [/feed documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/page/feed) is not stating it clearly.

So my calls were fetching like... all the posts since the beginning, with all the attachments.

Adding **?limit=10** or lower to the **/[page-id]/feed** query solved my problem.